# Can I combine two filters domain condition in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo, openerp-7

I created two filters:

```xml
<filter string="Board Room A" 
        name="location_board_a" 
        domain="[('location','=','Board A')]" />

<filter string="Today"  
        name="Today" 
        separator="1" 
        domain="[('start_datetime','&gt;=', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))), ('start_datetime','&lt;=', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))]" 
        help="Today"/>
```

How can I combine these two filters? I had tried using '&' but I was not able to get through it

Could anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the domains with a comma:

```xml
<filter string="Board Room A Today" 
        name="location_board_a_today" 
        domain="[('location','=','Board A'), ('start_datetime','&gt;=', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))), ('start_datetime','&lt;=', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=0)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))]" />
```